# User can add new input field with click on button - how to limit/set max fields?

Tags: javascript

The user can add a new input-field with a click on "Add". My problem is that there is no limit but I want to limit the max. input-fields to 50. Im not that good with js but I think it could done with:

> if id or input-field = 50
>
> than disable Add-button. And enable if id or input-field is under 50.

This is my code so far:

```js
function addFormField() {
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  $("#divTxt").append(
    "<p id='row" +
      id +
      "'><label for='txt" +
      id +
      "'>Field " +
      id +
      "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='20' name='txt[]' id='txt" +
      id +
      "'>&nbsp;&nbsp<a href='#' onClick='removeFormField(\"#row" +
      id +
      "\"); return false;'>Remove</a><p>"
  );

  id = id - 1 + 2;
  document.getElementById("id").value = id;
}

function removeFormField(id) {
  $(id).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" onClick="addFormField(); return false;">Add</a></p>
<form action="#" method="get" id="form1">
  <input type="hidden" id="id" value="1">
  <div id="divTxt"></div>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></p>
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Just use maxlength attribute like `maxlength="50"` for the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable and add 1 to it until the count reaches 50 like this

```js
let currentCount = 0;

function addFormField() {
  if(currentCount < 50){
  currentCount+= 1;
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  $("#divTxt").append(
    "<p id='row" +
      id +
      "'><label for='txt" +
      id +
      "'>Field " +
      id +
      "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='20' name='txt[]' id='txt" +
      id +
      "'>&nbsp;&nbsp<a href='#' onClick='removeFormField(\"#row" +
      id +
      "\"); return false;'>Remove</a><p>"
  );

  id = id - 1 + 2;
  document.getElementById("id").value = id;
  }else{
  alert('You can not add more then 50')
  }
}

function removeFormField(id) {
  $(id).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" onClick="addFormField(); return false;">Add</a></p>
<form action="#" method="get" id="form1">
  <input type="hidden" id="id" value="1">
  <div id="divTxt"></div>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @blacksheep your answer is just perfect :) I will accept it.

Comment: always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the length of child p tags of your div like this:

```
if($("#divTxt > p").length) < 50 ){
        var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
          $("#divTxt").append(
            "<p id='row" +
              id +
              "'><label for='txt" +
              id +
              "'>Field " +
              id +
              "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='20' name='txt[]' id='txt" +
              id +
              "'>&nbsp;&nbsp<a href='#' onClick='removeFormField(\"#row" +
              id +
              "\"); return false;'>Remove</a><p>"
          );

          id = id - 1 + 2;
          document.getElementById("id").value = id;
        }
```